# rspec integration test failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm working through Hartl's Rails tutorial on Chapter 5 where I'm creating integration tests for the new Users controller. After creating the rspec tests, I can't seem to get the two tests passing to check for content and the title of the signup webpage.

I've manually visited the webpage myself and both the content and title look fine. I've also used capybara's `save_and_open_page` to check what it's seeing and it appears exactly the same as me visiting the site sans the css formatting. I've also restarted both the rails and spork server, if that makes any difference.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Here's my rspec test `user_pages_spec.rb` :

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "UserPages" do

    subject { page }

    describe "Signup page" do

        before { visit signup_path; save_and_open_page }

        it { should have_content("Sign up") }
        it { should have_title(full_title("Sign up")) }
    end
end
```

Results for the test:

```
Run options: include {:locations=>{"./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb"=>[7]}}
FF

Failures:

  1) UserPages Signup page 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_content("Sign up") }
       expected #has_content?("Sign up") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) UserPages Signup page 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_title(full_title("Sign up")) }
       expected #has_title?("Rails Sample App | Sign up") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.06667 seconds
2 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:11 # UserPages Signup page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:12 # UserPages Signup page 

Randomized with seed 30695

[Finished in 0.7s with exit code 1]
```

rake routes

```
 Prefix Verb URI Pattern        Controller#Action
   root GET  /                  static_pages#home
   help GET  /help(.:format)    static_pages#help
  about GET  /about(.:format)   static_pages#about
contact GET  /contact(.:format) static_pages#contact
 signup GET  /signup(.:format)  users#new
```

new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign Up") %>

<h1>Sign Up</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/users/new.html.erb</p>
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
</head>
<body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
        <%= yield %>
        <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would help to see your layout and signup template.

Comment: Can you run rake routes and show us your routes?  I would expect you'd need to `visit new_user_registration_path`

Comment: @RubyRacer - i've added both of what you'd like to see